# Lineup label and checkbox in bootstrap forms

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is the generated HTML I have:

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="IsWebSiteActive">Website Active</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                <input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsWebSiteActive field is required." id="IsWebSiteActive" name="IsWebSiteActive" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="IsWebSiteActive" type="hidden" value="false">
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Also live link here: http://www.bootply.com/rD54mFrKhp
But label and checkbox of it are not lined up, what is the right way to do that? I "**prefer**" to keep the same structure I currently have and just add some `CSS` to fix it rather then restructuring the whole form .

Answer (score 0):

I know you would rather mess with `CSS`, but a simple change is remove your label with the class of `checkbox-inline` altogether.  That has a different purpose than what you are using it for.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is remove,

```
<label class="control-label col-md-2" for="IsWebSiteActive">Website Active</label>
```

Then everything should line up. It is not lining up due to the nesting of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the label tag. It isn't necessary.

http://www.bootply.com/4MzCPAemh4